# Chrome Inspect what do the THREE media queries bars signify

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, media-queries, inspect

In Chrome Inspect there is an option to 'show media queries' this results in two addional 'bars' being displayed near the top of the pane. (see pic.)
[image]

- A light-blue bar
- A yellowish bar, and
- The grey bar at the top (which is already there it seems).

What is the significance of these THREE bars?

Answer (score 3):

The grey bar on top is **NOT** a part of the media query bar. It is just used to set the responsive width to existing preset values.

Media query bars can be of 3 types.

- The blue bar shows "max-width" media queries.
- The orange bar shows "min-width" media queries
- A green bar ( if you had one ) would show media queries with both min and max widths.

You should be able to left click to apply the corresponding "triggering width", and right click to reveal the source. ( For green media queries, you can click again to toggle between min and max )